# Portfolio Optimization Problem: Variance Co-variance matrix

Tags: statistics, optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a set of daily returns and using these daily returns I calculated the average annual return for each asset and also by using the daily returns I calculated the var-cov matrix. To get optimize portfolios I calculated the daily portfolio risk and multiplied it by the root of 260 to annualize the  risk. Is this approach correct or is it more suitable to determine annual returns for a set of years and using those create the var-cov matrix?

Comment: Why should it be large for daily returns? Shouldn't it be small?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by large is degree of freedom would be larger for daily returns than annual returns.  That is what I meant.

Comment: I see. So my approach is correct right?

Comment: How many asset classes are you talking about.

Comment: five assets and I have 1600 days worth of data for each of the five assets

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZyAXP4syD8, this is what you want to watch